# I can't setting the "Associated Domain capability enabled"

Tags: ios, firebase-dynamic-links, apple-developer, apple-developer-account

I follow this article and try to make ios APP can use dynamic link redirect to my team's APP. Document link:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/flutter/receive

But I stuck on this step: On the Apple Developer site, create a provisioning profile for your app with the Associated Domain capability enabled.

[image]

In apple developer site, I click "Profiles" -> "match Development com.lightyearlabs.mamahealth"

[image]

Then, I click "Edit"

[image]

I found the "Enabled Capabilities" is grey and I can't edit it.

I want do this: On the Apple Developer site, create a provisioning profile for your app with the Associated Domain capability enabled.

Comment: Are you missing to enable on `Identifiers` menu?

Comment: I don't know where to find the Identifiers menu and what is it for.

Comment: It is where you create a bundle id and setup Apple services: push notification, associated domain, etc...

Answer (score 6):

Check the attached image, select your app bundle id then in `Capabilities` section, enable `Associated Domains`

[image]