# creating the ipa for app-store release with fastlane match

Tags: ios, flutter, match, app-store-connect, fastlane

i have created all my certificates using fastlane match in flutter. Like created the ad-hoc, development and app-store certificates, when i try to create an ipa for app-store i get this error everytime

```
error: exportArchive: "Runner.app" requires a provisioning profile with the Associated Domains feature.
```

i tryed to crete ipa using the ad-hoc certificate in xcode it works but i ma getting this error just with app-store certificate

am i missing something? can anybody help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72253207/i-cant-setting-the-associated-domain-capability-enabled/72254808#72254808)